# Mongodb, aggregate, how to suppress _id, yet keep the content inside it?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Need help with Mongodb Aggregate output format.

My data entry includes something look like this:

```
 {'parent_id': '133', 'status_id': '209101162445115_1199071210114767', 'author_id': '10209422198664172', 'comment_published': '2016-08-15 08:57:09'}
```

I need to count the number of occurrence of author_ids, given a matching parent_id. I did that with aggregate:

```
m = collection.aggregate([{"$match": {"parent_id":"437325203079413_1543639"}},
{ "$group": {"_id": {"author_id": "$author_id"}, "count":{"$sum":1}}},
{"$project": {"_id":1, "count":1}} ]) #this line does not make any difference in the output.

page =[]
for i in m:
    page.append(i)
print(page)
```

The output looks like this:

```
[{'_id': {'author_id': '10155430875324466'}, 'count': 1}, 
{'_id':{'author_id': '1249853341715138'}, 'count': 2}, 
{'_id': {'author_id': '10153804689530108'}, 'count': 1}]
```

I want the output to be in this format:

```
 [{'author_id': '10155430875324466', 'count': 1}, 
 {'author_id': '1249853341715138', 'count': 2}, 
 {'author_id': '10153804689530108', 'count': 1}]
```

Or this:

```
  [{'10155430875324466', 1}, 
 {'1249853341715138', : 2}, 
 {'10153804689530108', 1}]
```

I know a slow way of doing that in python, but I feel there should be better solutions. Is it possible to accomplish that within the aggregate query itself? Can anyone advise?

Comment: Just change your $ project stage as {"$project": {"author_id":$_id, "count":1}},And your second ouput you want is not a valid JSON.Please correct what you want.

Comment: Thanks. This one works if I also change the group to a direct projection: { "$group" : { "_id" : "$author_id", "count": { "$sum" : 1 } } }

Comment: Eventually, I need to store the output in a dictionary, like the second output. But if I can get the format of the first output, I can convert it to a dictionary in python. We cannot directly get the output in the second format from mongodb query, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this. You can use `author_id` as the grouping `_id` directly and then `project` the value in the `_id` as `author_id` in the final stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "parent_id" : "437325203079413_1543639" } }, 
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$author_id", "count": { "$sum" : 1 } } }, 
    { "$project" : { "_id" : 0, "author_id" : "$_id", "count" : 1 } } 
]);
```

or you can change the final `$project` stage as shown below.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "parent_id" : "437325203079413_1543639" } }, 
    { "$group" : { "_id" : { "author_id": "$author_id"}, "count": { "$sum" : 1 } } }, 
    { "$project" : { "_id" : 0, "author_id" : "$_id.author_id", "count":1 } } 
]);
```

Comment: I clicked it, right? I don't have enough authority to up vote the answer. Sorry about that.